# Appending to Start of File in C

Tags: c, linux, text, append, system-calls

How can I append to the start of a file (instead of the end) using system calls in C?

I have already read the man page of open(). I did not find any flag codes ( similar to O_APPEND) allowing me to append to the start of the file.

(Clarification - System Calls in Linux)

Comment: You can't. Create a new file and build it from scratch.

Comment: The correct word would be *prepend*, but I think the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 8):

Versions of Linux since 4.1 have [`fallocate(2)` with the `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` flag](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html), which allows you to insert a "hole" into a file which you can then write data into.  You can insert a hole at the beginning, fill it with data, then insert a new hole after the first one, and so on.  However, there are major caveats:

- It's only supported by certain filesystems (the man page mentions XFS and ext4)
- Holes can only be inserted in multiples of the filesystem block size (commonly 4 KB).  So this will only work if your data happens to be a multiple of that size, or if its format is such that you can safely pad it up to that size (e.g. if the file will be processed by a tool that ignores whitespace, in which case you could pad up to 4K with spaces or newlines).

Otherwise, there is nothing as general as `O_APPEND` for inserting at the start of a file or anywhere else.  Most filesystems are simply not designed in such a way that would make it possible to implement this efficiently.  Files are usually set up as a list of fixed-size blocks with a partial block at the end.  The OS can append to a file by updating the last partial block, then adding new blocks to the end of the list.  It may even be able to insert new blocks at other points in the list, as with `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE`.  But there's usually no provision for partial blocks anywhere in the list except at the end, so inserting data that is not a full block would require shifting the data in all other blocks, which requires rewriting all of it.

An extent-based filesystem like btrfs could in principle support inserting chunks of arbitrary lengths at the start of a file, by adding extents.  However, at least of as Linux 5.4.0, it's not actually supported, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

With `truncate` and `mmap`, it seems like this is possible without having to create a buffer file:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

bool file_prepend(int fd, const char *add)
{
    struct stat old;
    if (fstat(fd, &old) != 0)
        return false;
    size_t add_len = strlen(add);

    // Increase the file size to make space for the string
    if (ftruncate(fd, old.st_size + add_len) != 0)
        return false;
    char *mapped = mmap(NULL, old.st_size + add_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (!mapped)
        return false;

    // Now we can essentially treat the file as raw memory
    memmove(mapped + add_len, mapped, old.st_size);
    memcpy(mapped, add, add_len);
    munmap(mapped, old.st_size + add_len);
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR);
    assert(fd != -1);
    bool ok = file_prepend(fd, "Hello ");
    assert(ok);
    close(fd);
}
```

Before I run this program `foo.txt` looks like:

```
World
```

And after running the program it looks like:

```
Hello World
```

*By the way, I'm not an expert in `mmap` so my `prot` and `flags` params might be incorrect (though it works for me), feel free to correct me if I have done something wrong.*

Comment: Even though this may work, there's rarely any benefit doing this. While the file is being updated, another process may need the file. If locking is used, it'll have to wait. if locking is not used, it'll use a potentially corrupt file. Writing to a new file in the same filesystem as the old file and then move the new file into place will allow access to the file at all times and prevent reading a corrupt file. The only downside I see with that is that the new file gets a new inode.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The other downside is in case the file is very large or the filesystem is very full, such that there wouldn't be enough space to hold two copies.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, that's indeed a valid concern and that's probably even more often a real problem than my inode issue.